# Proof about mod properties

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $m>1$ be fixed. Show that if the integers $a_1,a_2,...,a_k$ have any two of the following three properties, they also have the third and hence constitute a complete residue system (mod m)

a) if $i \neq j$, then $a_i \not\equiv a_j(mod$ $m)$
b) if a is any integer, there is an index $i$ with $ 1 \leq i\leq k$ for which   $a \equiv a_k(mod$ $ m)$
c)k=m

Approach

Show a and b implies c

a is congruent to either $0 (mod$ $ m)$, $1 (mod$ $ m)$,.....,$m-1 (mod$ $ m)$, so there are exactly $m-1-0+1$ choices for a. Since a can't be congruent to two elements in the set by propert a), this implies $k=m$

Show b and c implies a

Considering just property b, we don't have any bound for k, so there can be even more elements such that $a_i$ and $b_j$ such that $a_i \equiv b_j(mod$ $ m)$, but hence we have $k=m$, we have to ensure that all $mod(m)$ is covered and this happens when k is at least m, so when $k=m$ if $i \neq j$, then $a_i \not\equiv a_j(mod$ $ m)$

Show a and c implies b
I don't know

I don't know if my idea is clear, so I need feedback.

Comment: Hint: a map between equal size finite sets is $1$-$1$ (injective) $\iff$ onto (surjective), i.e. the pigeonhole principle,

Answer (score 1):

Let' s consider an integer $a$. From Euclidean division we have that $\exists q,r\in \mathbb{Z}: a=qm+r$, where $r\in\{0,1,\dots,m-1\}$ and equivalently $a\equiv r(\mod m)$. Then, suppose that $a_k=q_km+r_k$, where, from $(c)$, $k=1,2,\dots,m$ and equivalently $a_k\equiv r_k ( \mod m)$, $k=1,2,\dots,m$. Now, we have that $r_1,r_2,\dots ,r_m\in\{0,1\dots, m-1\}$ and because of $(a)$ it follows that $\{r_1,r_2,\dots ,r_m\}=\{0,1\dots, m-1\}$. Finally, $r\in\{0,1\dots, m-1\}\Rightarrow r\in\{r_1,r_2,\dots ,r_m\}\Rightarrow r=r_k$ for some $k\in\{1,2,\dots,m\}$ and so $a\equiv a_k(\mod m)$, for some $k\in\{1,2,\dots,m\}$.